# How to install git source in requirements.txt?

Tags: python, django, heroku, github, pip

I have this code in requirements.txt But i remember that using this method i install but this time I got error only ...

```
static3==0.5.1
Twisted==15.0.0
urllib3==1.10.2
w3lib==1.11.0
zope.interface==4.1.2
pip install git+https://github.com/leonardoo/django-dropbox
```

I got the error when I do like this...

```
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-6.0.6-py2.7.egg/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2785, in scan_list
remote:            raise ValueError(msg, line, "at", line[p:])
remote:        ValueError: ('Expected version spec in', 'pip install git+https://github.com/rajasimon/python-twitter', 'at', ' install git+https://github.com/rajasimon/python-twitter')
```

Answer (score 6):

In your `requirements.txt` file:

```
...
zope.interface==4.1.2
-e git://github.com/leonardoo/django-dropbox.git#egg=django_dropbox
```

Check [`pip`'s documentation on the subject](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/reference/pip_install.html#git).

Comment: what is this `egg` thing and where do I take it?